# Decrementing a stocked item in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Good day,
I have created a script for an ERP solution, which holds items in a stocks table, with the same SKU appearing multiple times with different quantities and lots.
When I'm selling items, I want the stock quantity to be treated as a sum of all the items with  the same SKU, for example:

```
|item_id     |item_sku|   item_quantity|         lot|
|1           |10101001|   0            |    xyz     |
|2           |10101002|   5            |    012     |
|3           |10101001|   6            |    123     |
|4           |10101001|   7            |    456     |
|5           |10101001|   8            |    yf3     |
```

If I sell 14 units of 10101001, how would I go about writing the code that leaves item_id[1] untouched (as it's item_quantity is < 1), take all the quantity from item_id[3] and from item_id[4] and decrement item_id[5]'s quantity field by 1 `(14 = 6+7+1)` in an object-oriented approach? I thought about using a for each loop, but all I got was decrementing the quantity field over all the rows - so maybe I'm not writing it the right way. Also, I thought about treating the item_quantity as a sum, so grouping by SKU, summing up the item_quantity field, then subtracting the sold_quantity from that sum, but then how would I go about spreading the quantities in the database rows again?
I'm really stuck here, and this issue is driving me mad since Monday evening. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
LE: Here is my code:

```
$toSell = $value['sales_quantity'];
        $sum = StockDetail::where('sku', $product['sku'])->sum('stock_quantity');
        $updatedStock = $sum - $toSell;
//        StockDetail::where('sku', $product['sku'])->update(['stock_quantity' => $updatedStock]); // doesn't work for lots
        foreach($salesProduct as $key => $value) {
//
// more code here which is irrelevant to the issue I'm facing
//
            foreach($stockNotNull as $stock => $product) {
                if($toSell === 0) {
                    return;
                }
                do {
                    $product->stock_quantity->decrement();
                    $toSell--;
                    if ($product->stock_quantity === 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                } while($product->stock_quantity > 0 && $toSell > 0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Start by showing us what you tried. [ask].

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: You need more detail in your code attempt. What is `$stockNotNull`? Why is this inside another `foreach` loop? What is `$salesProducts`? You're misusing the `decrement()` function, which is for query builder, not Eloquent. Maybe you want `$product->stock_quantity -= 1; $product->save();`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is:

1. Start transaction.
2. Get all rows for given `item_sku` where `item_quantity > 0` ordered by `item_quantity` ascending.
3. Initialize `remaining_to_sell` with the quantity to sell
4. Iterate over rows, subtracting `min(remaining_to_sell, row.item_quantity` from `item_quantity` and save the row. Decrement that quantity from `remaining_to_sell`
5. Continue iterating until `remaining_to_sell` goes to zero.
6. If at end of rows the `remaining_to_sell` is not zero, you have no enough stock, so rollback the transaction and throw an error. Otherwise, commit it

I'll edit the answer soon with the actual code. I'm on mobile now.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($stockNotNull as $key => $value) {
            if ($toSell < 1) {
                return;
            }
            do {
                --$stockNotNull[$key]->stock_quantity;
                --$toSell;
                StockDetail::where('stock_id', $stockNotNull[$key]->stock_id)
                    ->update(['stock_quantity' => $stockNotNull[$key]->stock_quantity]);
            } while(($toSell != 0) && ($stockNotNull[$key]->stock_quantity != 0));
        }
```

It seems I forgot basic algorithms and loops since last I had to do this back in college...